# React Native multiline, value, smaller than placeholder in TextInput component

Tags: javascript, react-native

When adding text into a `<TextInput>` component with `multiline` set to `false` the `value` text matches the `placeholder` text font size, whereas if `multiline` is equal to `true`, the `value` text font size is smaller than the `placeholder` font size.

Is this a normal behaviour or a bug?

[image: Issue]

Edit:

```
/* @flow */

import React from 'react'
import Separator from './components/Separator'
import {Button, StyleSheet, TextInput, View} from 'react-native'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    subject: {
        height: 20,
    },
    body: {
        height: 100,
    },
})

export default class NewQuestion extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
        title: 'AIBU',
        headerLeft: (
            <Button
                onPress={() => {
                    navigation.goBack()
                }}
                title="Back"
            />
        ),
    })

    state = {
        subject: '',
        body: '',
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    autoFocus
                    onChangeText={subject => this.setState({subject})}
                    placeholder="Enter your AIBU subject..."
                    style={styles.subject}
                    value={this.state.subject}
                />
                <Separator />
                <TextInput
                    multiline
                    onChangeText={body => this.setState({body})}
                    placeholder="Enter your AIBU description..."
                    style={styles.body}
                    value={this.state.body}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: make sure you apply `fontSize` styling to your `TextInput`-s. Font size shouldn't be affected by whether the input is multiline or not.

Comment: @KyleKhalaf added

Comment: @dhorelik shouldn't have to apply a font size surely?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, the default font size is actually different for multiline and non-multiline `TextInput`-s. One way to handle this is by introducing another component which acts as an abstraction on top of `TextInput`:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
        fontFamily: 'System',
        fontStyle: 'normal',
        fontSize: 20,
        lineHeight: 20,
        letterSpacing: 0.6
    }
})

export default class AppTextInput extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        style: TextInput.propTypes.style
    }

    static defaultProps = {
        style: {}
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TextInput
                {...this.props}
                style={[
                    styles.text,
                    this.props.style
                ]}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Now you can just use `AppTextInput` the same way `TextInput` is supposed to be used, and all issues related to styling inputs are covered in a single place.

Comment: Good work round, but I believe this to be a bug, will raise a ticket with the React team, can't think of a plausible reason for this.

Comment: @JackC yep, that looks like an issue, default fontSize should be consistent.